# VB.NET Generator Troubles

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm currently writing a UUID Generator in Visual Basic 2008 ive got it to generate a UUID but without the - in them ive tried everything but nothing seems to be working ive been looking online but no solution has occurred, can anyone help me out? All the code is below maybe someone can figure it out.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TextBox1.Text = GenerateRandomString(8 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 12, False)
    End Sub
    Public Function GenerateRandomString(ByRef len As Integer, ByRef upper As Boolean) As String
        Dim rand As New Random()
        Dim allowableChars() As Char = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLOMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".ToCharArray()
        Dim final As String = String.Empty
        For i As Integer = 0 To len - 1
            final += allowableChars(rand.Next(allowableChars.Length - 1))
        Next
        Return IIf(upper, final.ToUpper(), final)
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Even though you've accepted an answer, your code above is wrong for another reason.  You cannot have letters g-z in a UUID.  Only 0-9 and a-f.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why do you do it yourself ? You can use the framework instead :

Guid.NewGuid.ToString

And then remove the unwanted "-" using replace()

Comment: oh that worked thanks! not familiar with Guid.NewGuid.ToString but it worked, thanks again.

Comment: If you want to thank me : upvote my answer and/or flag it has the one that solves your problem : It will give me some reputation points... :-)

Comment: O yes indeed... But my "SO" explanation is still valid, because there is no "correct answer" flagged for the moment. So I though that this was still a problem for the OP.

Comment: Not only you write the same answer as mine, but manage to suggest something totally unecessary to remove the separators when you could get the value without them. Well sometime I wish to know the logic behind certain choices.

Comment: @Steve : Your comment made me sad.... I hope that it was your goal. Good will, man, good will. That's all it was.

Comment: Good will and revenge downvote? Fine. I leave to your good will

Comment: Your comment was so passive-aggressive, i though it was you that downvoted me. I don't know how to see this info. Yes, it was fight back. Sorry if it wasn't you. I can not undo this...

Answer (score 1):

The [Guid structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Guid(v=vs.110).aspx) NewGuid method could generate the output string in many possible ways and, probably, its output is more unique than writing your own generator

```
Sub Main
    Dim g = Guid.NewGuid()

    Console.WriteLine(g.ToString("N")) ' out = 87f1778f4e2d4db1951fbc48ed9eb722
    Console.WriteLine(g.ToString("D")) ' out = 87f1778f-4e2d-4db1-951f-bc48ed9eb722
    Console.WriteLine(g.ToString("P")) ' out = (87f1778f-4e2d-4db1-951f-bc48ed9eb722)
    Console.WriteLine(g.ToString("B")) ' out = {87f1778f-4e2d-4db1-951f-bc48ed9eb722}
    Console.WriteLine(g.ToString("X")) ' out = {0x87f1778f,0x4e2d,0x4db1,{0x95,0x1f,0xbc,0x48,0xed,0x9e,0xb7,0x22}}
End Sub
```

So, if I understand your requirements, you need the ToString("N") format

Answer (score 0):

Actually have to do as @Steve answering, but for learning.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim gen = GenerateRandomString(32, False)
        TextBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(gen, "(.{8})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{12})", "$1-$2-$3-$4-$5-$6")
    End Sub
    Public Function GenerateRandomString(ByRef len As Integer, ByRef upper As Boolean) As String
        Dim rand As New Random()
        Dim allowableChars() As Char = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLOMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".ToCharArray()
        Dim final As String = String.Empty
        For i As Integer = 0 To len - 1
            final += allowableChars(rand.Next(allowableChars.Length - 1))
        Next
        Return IIf(upper, final.ToUpper(), final)
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: 'Regex' is not declared, i imported Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions, then it the code was fine but it generated a long random line without -

Comment: And you can's use characters g-z in a UUID.